# Yii2 AJAX Validation upon filling Dynamic Forms

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, yii2, dynamic-forms

I am working on a Yii2 Project and I have a widget of dynamic form. My goal is to get the total percentage of all the items from the dynamic form everytime an items is added and check if it equals to 100. I want to do this using AJAX but I am not very familiar with it. Thank you in advance. Here is the screen cap of the page.[image]

Comment: I can provide the code for the dynamic form if needed.

Comment: Basically the validation from your models will be implemented by dynamic form widget.. Can you include your source code here?